# Mongoose CastError on updating collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I got two collections on my mongodb database which are room and question.

[image]

[image]

I can add just fine, but when I tried to edit the question collection, I got this error

[image]

This is my code for updating it, and linked it to the room questions

[image]

what did I do wrong?

Comment: Your Question schema has a field _answerStart_, while your update query has a field _startAnswer_. Is it intentional?

Comment: Additionally, if you are using **update**, then why are you assigning req.body.time to **answerStart**?

Comment: @AnkitGomkale I'm really sorry for the confusion. I already fixed all the typos and clean up the code, but still cannot update it, got the same error.